# Modular form-based Java web application with pluggable modules for each year

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have a conceptual design for a web application in my head, but I have no idea if it's possible to implement it with current frameworks.

Basically, what I'd like to do is have a "core" web application that can be deployed as a war.  Then I'd to be able to develop individual bundles (jar/war/???) that encapsulate forms and input screens for each year (they can change quite a bit from year to year) that can be deployed separately.  Once a new year is deployed, the core app, either through configuration files or configuration parameters read from a database, makes the new year's forms available within the core web app.  All prior deployed form years would still be available.

The reasoning for this design is to eliminate regression testing as much as possible by encapsulating each year into a separate module.  Each year, when it came time to develop the new forms, you'd just make a copy of the prior year's project, rename it, and make whatever changes were required for that year from the prior year's forms before building and deploying it.

This design would also allow you to bug-fix earlier years in isolation without disturbing any other years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification / technology I'd recommend looking at is [OSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi).

Some high profile Java products such as Eclipse IDE and Nuxeo ECM are using it and they are very easily customizable (everything, even the core of the product is an extensible/customizable component).